# encode special character in html entities in perl

Tags: perl, html-entities

I have a string where special characters like `!` or `"` or `&` or `#` or `@`, ... can appear. How can I convert in the string

```
str = " Hello "XYZ" this 'is' a test & so *n @."
```

automatically every special characters with their html entities, so that I get this:

```
str = " Hello &quot ;XYZ&quot ; this &#39 ;is&#39 ; a test &amp ; so on @"
```

I tried

```
$str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str);
```

but it does a partial work the `@` is not transformed in `&#64` ;

**SOLUTION:**

1) with your help (Quentin and vol7ron) I came up with this solution(1)

```
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'@'} = '&#64;';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'!'} = '&#33;';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'#'} = '&#35;';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'%'} = '&#37;';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'.'} = '&#46;';
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'*'} = '&#42;';
$str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str, q{@"%'.&#*$^!});
```

2) and I found a shorter(better) solution(2) found it [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=640603):

```
$str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str, '\W');
```

the '\W' does the job

**@von7ron** with solution(1) you will need to specify the characters you want to translate as **Quentin** mentioned earlier even if they are on the translation table.

Comment: I already mentioned that, which was my second point I made: `You then need to specify the character you want to translate, if you don't it uses '<>&"', so I added both '@' and '.`  If you don't supply anything it lists it uses `<>*"` by default, if you list anything else, it's not going to append default, it replaces it, so if you want the default characters too, you have to include in your own list, which is what I showed you.

Comment: BTW you don't need all those `$HTML::Entities::char2entity{...}` lines, and if you did, that's not the proper way to use it.  You only need them if you're going to be putting in non-ASCII characters.  The `\W` was a good find - the only special (non-alphanumeric) character that, that solution won't escape is underscores (`_`), but that's not a big concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add a character to the translation table (char2entity hash).

```
$HTML::Entities::char2entity{'@'} = '&#64;';

my $str      =  q{ Hello "XYZ" this 'is' a test & so on @};
my $encoded  =  HTML::Entities::encode_entities( $str, q{<>&"'@} );
```

1. The above adds `@`, which will be translated to `&#64;`.
2. You then need to specify the characters you want to translate, if you don't it uses `<>&"`, so I added both `@` and `'`.  Notice, I didn't have to add the `'` to the translation table, because it's already there by default.
3. You don't need to add ASCII characters (0-255) to the char2entity hash, since the module will do it automatically.

---

***Note:** Setting the char2entity for `@`, was done as an example.  The module automatically sets numerical entities for ASCII characters (0-255) that weren't found.  You'd have to use it for unicode characters, though.*

Comment: i am getting the same result &quot ;Hello &quot ;XYZ&quot ; this 'is' a test &amp ; so on @&quot ; the @ and ' are not encoded           $str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str, q{<>&"@'#%!});

Comment: @mamasaye: Try `q{<>&"'@!#}` the order of the single quote might mess up the result -- not sure why that is (I don't think `@'` is a variable), this could be an internal module (or possibly perl) error -- I've updated the solution

Answer (score 5):

`@` isn't transformed because it isn't considered to be a "special character". It can be represented in ASCII and has no significant meaning in HTML.

You can expand the range of characters that are converted with the second argument to the function you are using, [as described in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aEntities).

Comment: … which works. `# perl -MHTML::Entities -E'my $str = "\@"; $str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str,"@#%!&"); say $str;'` outputs `&#64;`

Comment: i tried `code`<br> $str=HTML::Entities::encode_entities($str,'@#%!&');<br>`code`and i get`code`<br>" Hello "XYZ" this 'is' a test &amp ; so on &#64 ;"<br>`code`now its ignoring the ' or " which are html entities.what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @mamesaye — The argument **changes** the characters to encode, it doesn't add to them.

Comment: @mamesaye — If you don't specify what characters to encode, it encodes a default set. If you do, then it encodes the one you tell it to encode and doesn't encode the default set.

Answer (score -1):

Cheap, dirty, and ugly, but works:

```
my %translations;
$translations{'"'}  = '&quot ;';
$translations{'\''} = '&#39 ;';
etc...


sub transform()
{
    my $str = shift;
    foreach my $character (keys(%translations))
    {
        $str =~ s/$character/$translations{$character}/g;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: The OP has a perfectly serviceable module to do that already. Wheel reinvention is not usually a good idea.